# Jquery post is not working due to htaccess file in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, codeigniter

I placed a .htaccess code to remove index.php from URL in amazon server. After placing that my Jquery post function is not working for me.Please help me with this issue.Here is my .htaccess code.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And jquery post code is

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url();?>user/createfile",
{newfile: value},function(result)
{
$('#create').hide();
});
```

Comment: What's not working? What error are you getting? Details, please.

Comment: My jquery post is not redirecting to "createfile" when I removed "index.php" from URL

Comment: I deactivated htaccess and Tried . Then my jquery post is working.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
 $.post("<?php echo site_url('user/createfile'); ?>", {newfile: value}).done(function(result){

    alert(result);
        $('#create').hide();


        });
```

use site_url instead of base_url()

Comment: Try this code for htaccess RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Use this(.htaccess Should be placed outside the application folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```